# python string escape sequence simulation is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, escaping

```
print('12\b45')
>>>145
```

this is actual output. but in python 3.8 idle it printed as

```
>>>1245
```

the backspace escape sequence is not generating!!.also I checked in command prompt that giving the actual output

Comment: Is your question about Python 2.7 or 3.8? Please remove one of the wrong tags. As a side note, IDLE is not designed for serious development and certainly not for production-grade execustion.

Comment: Interpreting escape sequences is a feature of the shell. Idle does not support that.